# What is this NASA UAV, and what is its function?

Tags: aircraft-identification, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

For the question [What's up with the “What's Up at Wallops” app?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26246/12102) I was reviewing the [What's up at Wallops](https://www.wallopsisland.org/) website and drifted to the [launch photos](https://www.wallopsisland.org/launch-photos/) page where I saw this aircraft. I did not find a caption, and a quick reverse image search in google did not return any helpful results.

> [image: not a space plane]

I am fairly confident that *it is not* a "spaceplane".

What is this NASA UAV, and what is its function?

[image: NASA UAV aircraft]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is a Northrop Grumman RQ-4 Global Hawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_RQ-4_Global_Hawk). [NASA has done some research on civilian applications for drones](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/111761main_UAV_Capabilities_Assessment.pdf) and this one [appears to be for storm research.](http://guardianlv.com/2013/09/nasa-deploying-global-hawk-drones-for-storm-studies-video/) You can find more [info on the project here](https://espo.nasa.gov/hs3/).

Comment: Thanks! fyi I've just asked [How did Northrop Grumman propose to make the Global Hawk nuclear powered?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49890/14213)